# AWS cloudformation WAF request header (x-token) is not empty and allow it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, web-application-firewall

Trying to create a cloud formation template to configure WAF with header empty or not check condition and pass the request accoringly to the ALB . Couldnt find the right template yet. Any pointers would be appreciated.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-string-conditions.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-regex-conditions.html

Comment: Hey, do you still need this question answered? I'm happy to answer it but conscious it's from 2019